# Access to a block view in a paragraph in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I created a paragraph in drupal which has a reference to a block.
In the preprocess I did :

```
$variables['bloc_video'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($bp);
```

And in my twig file I just called it like that :

```
{{bloc_video}}
```

The view is unfortunately not correct.

I want my preprocess to call my block view in another twig file. How can I do that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module (it is very useful also for other cases). [Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2964457) you can find more about including blocks in twig with Twig Tweak module.

In you case you can use:

```
{{ drupal_entity('block', 'block_content') }}
```

However, if you would still like to do it programmatically, check [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/171733/69507).